# Yii save formated text in file

Tags: php, yii

I need to save formated text into file to OS and the to read the file and update it. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to save formated text into file to OS". How is the text formatted, what OS. What have you tried?

Comment: Text is formated with spaces and new lines. I use linux

Comment: Then simply use file_get_contents and file_put_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, just use file_get_contents() and file_put_contents() functions.

Have you heard of www.php.net ?